# Implementing IDuplexSessionChannel for Message Interception & Replacement

Tags: wcf, caching, nettcpbinding, channel, .net

I would like to intercept WCF messages on the client side. I cannot use any MessageInspector for this, because I would like to implement a client side WCF cache. If the request has been cached before, the response should come from the cache, otherwise the request ist forwarded to the service.

As I am using netTcpBinding and netNamedPipeBinding, the "simple" way, implementing IRequestChannel is not possible. I need to implement IDuplexSessionChannel. Now, I am looking for a working sample how to intercept and replace messages.

---

**But why is this important?**

In theory WCF-services, as all other calls that possibly goes over a network, should have coarse-grained interfaces. The reason is obvious: WCF has tons of features to secure the connection, enable reliable-messing, ensures authentication, enable transactions (... continued ...). This will not come for free, obviously.

In practice we ofen encounter "exeptions" from that rules. Services that are called a thousend times in one service method and other violations of best practices. Well, of course the best way to deal with this situation would be to redesign the services. Unfortunately, that rarely happens (you name the reasons ...).

That is where caching comes into play. There are, basically, two ways of doing this:

1. Implementing a solution that needs to rewrite parts of your applications. One way of doing this is to write a proxy-caller (e.g. using generics for that).
2. List item

Implementing a "transparent" solution, that works with all WCF-services, without any modifications

For obvious reasons the second solution seems more promising. Again, there are two alternatives:

1. Writing a **servers-side**-caching solution, using WCF behaviors and IOperationInvoker. This is pretty straightforward to accomplish and the web gives you some good samples how to do this. Such as olution is acceptable, if the service to be cached is pretty expensive in its methods, e.g. loading lots of information from a database, so that looking up the result in your cache is much faster than perform all necessary calculations and IO-operations. However, the WCF-call is still there, with all overhead that comes with it. The advantage is, that you only need to define that behavior once in your service and all clients of this service will benefit from the cache.
2. Writing a **client-side-caching**-solution, that prevents the WCF-call, if the response is already in the cache. This, of course, prevents all the WCF-overhead, but requires to define the (endpoint) behavior within all clients that accesses the services to be cached (e.g. any master data service or any other "slowly changing dimension"-services).

The second solution is much more complicated, as you need a channel factory,  (and / or a listener) and an implementation of the channel itself. The channel could be a IRequestChannel or a IDuplexSessionChannel. Again, you will find a working solution for the first type on the web, but that, naturally, will not work for netTcpBining or netNamedPipeBinding, which uses the IDuplexSessionChannel. That is, why I am looking for a sample that illustrates how to do it right.

Just to give an impression of what the benefits would be: One solution, that has a long-running service method, the execution time is (approx. 150000 calls of other services within that service):

- netTcpBinding, no caching: 65 minutes
- netNamedPipeBinding, no caching: 40 minutes
- netNamedPipeBinding, server-side-caching: 27 minutes
- netNamedPipeBinding, client-side-caching: 19 minutes

The no. of calls drops fro 150000 to about 40000 in that szenario. However, my solution for client-side-caching will not work well for duplex-channels and other special commmunication types. Therefor, I am looking for a sample.

Any help would be appreciated.